How to destroy/remove Texture after collision in java box2d
I'm coding a simple Arkanoid/Breakout game and have problems with removing the bricks. I'm able to destroy the body but the texture is still there. I'm a beginner so is there a simple way to remove it or are there more things to understand first?



Please share code as text, not as an image. This makes your question more accessible to search, translation, and screen-reading features, helping get input from more experts, faster. Visit the [help] if you need support formatting your code.

You need to call remove on the Actor.
I can't see what your Box2DActor class looks like from your screenshots, but a solution would be to find the Brick instance that has the body that is being destroyed (bodyToDestroy), and call remove() on that.

Thanks for the quick answer. I added the Box2DActor.

Do you keep your Bricks in a list or something?

i build bricks with a list yes but does it matter? the contact listener recognizes a contact with one brick. Isnt it possible to pick this one out and remove?

I asked about the list because it would be easy to iterate over the Bricks in that list to find the Brick that has the Body to remove. It is not enough to destroy the Body, you also need to remove the Actor (Brick).
